# How to toggle checkbox states

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I can't uncheck a checkbox after I checked it (all via JS/Jquery).

Code:

```
//Works perfect
function showL(labelObj)
{   
    var cb = $(labelObj).prev()[0]; 
    $(cb).prop('checked', true);    
}  

//Does NOT work
function hideL(labelObj)
{
    var cb = $(labelObj).next()[0];
    //$(cb).attr('checked', false);
    $(cb).prop('checked', false);
}
```

**update**

It's the same object in both functions:
[image]

Comment: That isn't targeting the same element, in one you get the next element, and another the previous one. Note you will also want to include your HTML.

Comment: Not the problem, but why are you getting `cb` as a reference to the DOM element and then creating a new jQuery object? You can just say `$(labelObj).prev().prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @nnnnnn Just for testing... I thought the way I was doing it before was the problem.

Comment: You need to share the relevant html and how these methods are called

Comment: Can you share the html and method invoking part instead of an image

Comment: @nnnnnn No idea why, but the one line code that `nnnnn` posted made it. Isn't it the same thing ?

Comment: They should be the same thing *if* `labelObj` is exactly one element. If `$(labelObj)` could select more than one element then `$(labelObj).next()` will also select more than one element and so then by using `[0]` you would get the first of those which might not be the right one. You don't have duplicate ids or something?

Comment: @nnnnnn Not duplicated  IDs... Not really sure why it didn't work with my code. But you solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function{
    var propState = $(this).prop('checked'); // grab the checkbox checked state.
    propState === true ? propState = false : propState = true; // ternary operation. If box is checked uncheck it. if it is not checked check it.
}
```

It will work on all checkboxes.

Comment: This doesn't really help at all with the OP's problem, given they're already trying to use `.prop()` and they think they've selected the right element, and they didn't say anything about click or other events. Also, the ternary operation in your function doesn't change the state of the actual checkbox, it just changes the `propState` variable (which, incidentally, could be done more simply with `propState = !propState;`).